# Doctrine 2 get matched rows count instead of affected while update

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have such code:

```
    $updateSQL = "UPDATE `Rooms` R SET R.Revenue = {$s['Revenue']}, R.Ave_rent = {$s['Ave_Rent']}
                  WHERE R.Facility_ID={$s['Facility_ID']} AND R.Cur_Year={$s['Year']} AND R.Cur_Month={$s['Month']}";

    $affectedRows = $this->em->getConnection()->executeUpdate($updateSQL);
    if($affectedRows > 0) { ... }
```

Everything works fine. The only issue that I need to know how much rows MATCH to my condition `R.Facility_ID={$s['Facility_ID']} AND R.Cur_Year={$s['Year']} AND R.Cur_Month={$s['Month']}` I don't if care were they affected or not I don't want to use one more select.

Maybe there is some setting for mysql to count row affected even if was the same?

Comment: Why do you use Doctrine2 when you don't use the objects and make single queries?

Comment: Because I use them in 100 other places. Let's think that I can't and dont want to use them here. Question is not about use doctrine for native queries or not.

Comment: you could probably look at mysql log, to see how many rows were updated...but if you want it displayed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL itself returns the number of affected rows, not the number of matched rows, see [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html#id765711).

<strike>If Doctrine would do what you want here, it would have to execute another query. If you really need this, you will have to do this yourself.</strike>

edit: reading one sentence later in the docs, I see that [mysql_info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-info.html) ([mysqli_info](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php) in PHP) returns this information.

Comment: Hello
Thank you for the answer. Can you use mysql_info with doctrine. I'm not being able to, it returns me null. I'm using
mysqli_info($this->getEntityManager()->getConnection())
with "this" being an AbstractRestfulController.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this one: Logic is there through SQL but...

```
SELECT COUNT(R.Facility_ID), R.Cur_Year, r.Cur_Month from Rooms R
inner join
ON R.Facility_ID={$s['Facility_ID']} AND R.Cur_Year={$s['Year']} AND R.Cur_Month={$s['Month']};
```

Or even something like this to your php:

```
$aff_rows = 0;

foreach($sql as $current_sql)
{
 $updateResult = mysqli_query($link, $current_sql); 
 $aff_rows = $aff_rows + mysqli_affected_rows($link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can add another field to DB, like timestamp, and set it to `NOW()` in your update statement, that way all matched rows will be affected.